# Where can I find the definitions of System.Collections.Concurrent classes in the mono source code?

Tags: c#, collections, mono

I am looking for the source code of the `System.Collections.Concurrent` classes, especially `ConcurrentQueue` and `ConcurrentDictionary` in the mono sources. I am unable to find them.

I was looking in the `corlib` Directory:

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/corlib

but it does not contain the `System.Collections.Concurrent` package. Even using the repository search feature of github did not yield the source code.

There was already [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352050/in-the-mono-soure-code-where-can-i-find-mscorlib-dll-class-definitions) which asked a similar thing, but the links provided in the answer are dead. So where are the collection sources in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono from version 4.0 started to include source code that Microsoft opened sourced as [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource).

The last version of Mono that included its own version of the concurrent classes code was Mono 3.12 and that has the [ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentDictionary classes](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-3.12.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Concurrent).

For later versions of Mono the source code for the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://github.com/mono/referencesource/tree/mono/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent) namespace is in the [mono/referencesource](https://github.com/mono/referencesource) GitHub repository, which is a fork of Microsoft's [reference source repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource).